# Colon designated list of colon itemized sentences

Tags: lists, colons

I'm just seeing dots, working with colons. Is it correct to use a colon to introduce a list of items which begin with colons? Or is it quite superfluous?

Typically, I seem to employ this for lists of definitions, for example:

> The database stores three types of data:
>
> junk: data that no-one wants anymore.
>  
>   useless: serves no purpose whatsoever.
>   irrelevant: haikus about birds.

I've found [this resource](http://lilt.ilstu.edu/golson/punctuation/colon.html) to be pretty helpful when considering how I'm using colons, but as I'm writing a list like this I keep thinking there might be a better way, something clearer that doesn't overuse the punctuation.

All help appreciated!

Comment: I have personally no problem with colon, especially not in documentation. I would even bold the word before it: **junk**: data that no-one wants anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Along with mplungjan, I believe a colon is fine in those cases. But if you wanted to limit its use you could consider a dash instead (I like spaces around em-dashes):

> The database stores three types of data:
>
> junk — data that no-one wants anymore;
> useless — serves no purpose whatsoever;
> irrelevant — haikus about birds.

This serves to set off the description of each type more clearly from its headword.

Given that it is a list, a semi-colon at the end of each list item is also valid. Or you could rely on the layout and not have any punctuation at the end of each line. A full-stop at the end of each line isn't grammatical — the whole quote forms the complete sentence — and it breaks it up too much.